# update with aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have this table

SalesTable

```
ProdID SalesmanBeforeName SalesmanBeforeDT SalesmanCurrentName SalesmanCurrentDT SalesmanAfterName SalesmanAfterDT

1011   NULL               NULL             Tom                 5/5/2019 10:53:52 NULL              NULL
1012   NULL               NULL             John                5/5/2019 11:36:47 NULL              NULL
1011   NULL               NULL             Adam                5/5/2019 10:41:35 NULL              NULL
1011   NULL               NULL             Matt                5/5/2019 09:22:11 NULL              NULL
1012   NULL               NULL             Rita                5/5/2019 12:50:19 NULL              NULL
1012   NULL               NULL             Nash                5/5/2019 11:09:26 NULL              NULL
```

I want to fill the null values with the sales before and after

```
ProdID SalesmanBeforeName SalesmanBeforeDT SalesmanCurrentName SalesmanCurrentDT SalesmanAfterName SalesmanAfterDT

1011   Adam               5/5/19 10:41:35  Tom                 5/5/2019 10:53:52 NULL              NULL
1012   Nash               5/5/29 11:09:26  John                5/5/2019 11:36:47 Rita              5/5/19 12:50:19
1011   Matt               5/5/19 09:22:11  Adam                5/5/2019 10:41:35 Tom               5/5/19 10:53:52
1011   NULL               NULL             Matt                5/5/2019 09:22:11 Adam              5/5/19 10:41:35
1012   John               5/5/19 11:36:47  Rita                5/5/2019 12:50:19 NULL              NULL
1012   NULL               NULL             Nash                5/5/2019 11:09:26 John              5/5/19 11:36:47
```

I tried this update statement but failed

```
UPDATE S1
SET SalesmanBeforeName = S3.SalesmanCurrentName,
SalesmanBeforeDT = S3.SalesmanCurrentDT
FROM SalesTable S1 INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 S2.ProdID, S2.SalesmanCurrentName, S2.SalesmanCurrentDT FROM SalesTable S2 WHERE S1.ProdID = S2.ProdID AND S2.SalesmanCurrentDT < S1.CurrentDT ORDER BY S2.SalesmanCurrentDT DESC) S3
ON S1.ProdID = S3.ProdID
```

Comment: Please add a problem statement which describes the logic behind your update.  What is it doing?

Comment: May I suggest reading up on the `LAG` & `LEAD` functions?

Comment: `ON T.ProdID = TB.ProdID` what is T and what is `TB` - looks like here is your problem

Comment: We would usually avoid redundancy in our databases. I would only store `ProdID`, `SalesmanName` and `SalesmanDT` in the table. You can always write a query to get the previous and/or following salesman. Create a view, if you want that more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use for [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions that were added in SQL Server 2012. It is much more efficient than self-join.

I use CTE below to make the query very clear and easy to read.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ProdID
        ,SalesmanCurrentName
        ,SalesmanCurrentDT
        ,SalesmanBeforeName
        ,SalesmanBeforeDT
        ,SalesmanAfterName
        ,SalesmanAfterDT
        ,LEAD(SalesmanCurrentName) OVER (PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY SalesmanCurrentDT) AS NewSalesmanAfterName
        ,LEAD(SalesmanCurrentDT)   OVER (PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY SalesmanCurrentDT) AS NewSalesmanAfterDT
        ,LAG(SalesmanCurrentName)  OVER (PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY SalesmanCurrentDT) AS NewSalesmanBeforeName
        ,LAG(SalesmanCurrentDT)    OVER (PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY SalesmanCurrentDT) AS NewSalesmanBeforeDT
    FROM SalesTable
)
UPDATE CTE
SET
     SalesmanBeforeName = NewSalesmanBeforeName
    ,SalesmanBeforeDT   = NewSalesmanBeforeDT
    ,SalesmanAfterName  = NewSalesmanAfterName
    ,SalesmanAfterDT    = NewSalesmanAfterDT
;
-- SELECT * FROM CTE
```

You can comment the `UPDATE` part at first and run the `SELECT * FROM CTE` to confirm that results are correct and then perform the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the statement below :

```
UPDATE S1
   SET S1.SalesmanBeforeName = S2.SalesmanCurrentName,
       S1.SalesmanBeforeDT   = S2.SalesmanCurrentDT 
  FROM SalesTable as S1
  INNER JOIN SalesTable as S2 
     ON S1.ProdID = S2.ProdID
  WHERE S2.SalesmanCurrentDT < S1.SalesmanCurrentDT;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/MZR6513)</kbd>